# Как правильно сохранять данные в Android?

Tags: android, база-данных, android-sqlite

Есть приложение, которое время от времени получает данные с сервера. По этим данным строится таблица. Данные из хранилища приложения будут запрашиваться не очень часто, максимум 1—2 раза за одну сессию работы приложения. Данные не конфиденциальны и не требуют защиты. Их объём, как правило, не больше 50 КБ, но могут накапливаться с месяцами работы приложения. В конечном итоге, размер хранимой информации в приложении не будет превышать 1 МБ.

Я знаю, что `Shared Preference` хорошо подходит для различных настроек приложения. SQLite для больших объёмов данных. Я склоняюсь к SQLite, но не уверен до конца. Что из этого нужно и правильно использовать для решения моей проблемы, и почему? Желательно указать, почему так считаете, или ссылку на статью, где это описывается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. У вас данные структуированные, строятся таблицы, поэтому лучше использовать sqlite. Sharedpreferences нужен для хранения простых каких либо значений,а не таблиц